# Could FIDE make a rule allowing for a visual announcement of check and checkmate?

Tags: rules, checkmate, fide, check

Using verbal methods in announcing check and checkmate in tournaments is, for the arbiters, the players etc, unpleasant. But, on the other hand, prohibiting any means for an announcement is annoying for some beginners and even a few high players. Could FIDE make a rule stating that one could instead use a visual method?

Comment: The existing guidelines for disabled players already allow for that, don't they? (See https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/D0412.) I would expect a chess player feeling verbal communication to be unpleasant could be considered disabled in the meaning of the FIDE handbook and other relevant regulations.)

Comment: https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/D0412 Working version of @user30536's link which ate some punctuation.

Comment: There is a visual method- it's called a chessboard.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose they could make whatever rules they want, but it would seem to be unnecessary.

According to the [FIDE Laws of Chess](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/E012018):

> 5.1.1 The game is won by the player who has checkmated his opponent’s king. This immediately ends the game, provided that the move producing the checkmate position was in accordance with Article 3 and Articles 4.2 – 4.7.

The game is ended whether or not the checkmate is announced, and there is nothing in the rules that says a player must make such an announcement. A player is just as free to make a visual indication as they are to make a verbal one, and need not make any indication at all.

Announcing check is also not mentioned in the FIDE rules. So, again, it would seem that a player would be just as free to make a visual indication as a verbal one, and need not announce at all (indeed, it's uncommon to announce check at high or even medium levels.)

In either case, one must be careful not to distract or annoy their opponent or players on other boards.

Answer (score 2):

> Could FIDE make a rule allowing for a visual announcement of check and checkmate?

Rule changes have to be approved by the rules commission. Rule changes are only made after extensive discussion and deliberation. Adding an unnecessary source of distraction like this is a bad idea so, while in theory they could, it is unlikely that such a suggestion would even reach the stage of being considered let alone adopted.

Comment: I mean by visual method using a sign from the hand, for example. This sign from the Hand should be customary.